# Is it possible to generate artifacts for all the tables at once with MyBatis Generator?

Tags: automation, mybatis

I am using MyBatis Generator 1.3.1 from the command-line. I read in the documentation that I need to specify at least one table for object generation, but I was hoping maybe it is possible to use some wildcard and have mappers for all the tables generated at once? We don't want to use Hibernate, because MyBatis seems to handle custom types in the database better.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL wildcards, ie:

```
<table tableName="%">
    <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="true"/>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, @bhutten! Do you know a similar trick for <mappers> section of the configuration.xml file that would generate paths to all generated mappers at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964398/mybatis-generator-how-to-generate-all-tables-for-a-specified-schema/52128862#52128862)

If you use MySQL, The crucial point is this:
**`<table schema="dbName" tableName="%"</table>`** and
**`<property name="nullCatalogMeansCurrent" value="true" />`**
reference:**http://www.mybatis.org/generator/usage/intro.html**

Settings like this:

```
<generatorConfiguration>
<properties resource="mybatis-generator/generator.properties"></properties>
<classPathEntry location="${driverLocation}"/>
<context id="default" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">
    <property name="javaFileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <commentGenerator type="org.zhang.generator.MyCommentGenerator">
        <property name="suppressDate" value="true"/>
        <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true"/>
    </commentGenerator>

    <jdbcConnection
            driverClass="${driverClassName}"
            connectionURL="${url}"
            userId="${username}"
            password="${password}">
        <property name="nullCatalogMeansCurrent" value="true" />
    </jdbcConnection>

    <javaTypeResolver>
        <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="true"/>
    </javaTypeResolver>

    <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.entity" targetProject="src/main/java">

        <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
    </javaModelGenerator>


    <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="daoMappers" targetProject="src/main/resources">
        <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
    </sqlMapGenerator>


    <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="com.dao" targetProject="src/main/java" type="XMLMAPPER">
        <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
    </javaClientGenerator>

    <table schema="dbName" tableName="%"
           enableSelectByPrimaryKey="true"
           enableCountByExample="false"
           enableUpdateByExample="false"
           enableDeleteByExample="false"
           enableSelectByExample="false"
           selectByExampleQueryId="false"
           enableDeleteByPrimaryKey="false"
           enableUpdateByPrimaryKey="false"
           enableInsert="false">

        <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="true"></property>
    </table>
</generatorConfiguration>
```